# Работа с WebBrowser в delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Я открываю в `WebBrowser` страницу и у меня все работает (например гугл):

```
WebBrowser1.Navigate('http://www.google.com');
```

Мне нужно взять `html` файл (который храниться у меня на компе), добавить его в проект (чтобы html не болтался отдельным файлом, а был в проекте) и открыть этот html файл через браузер.

Подскажите как это сделать?

Comment: WebBrowser1.Navigate('C:/WebServers/home/test1.ru/www/index.html');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как RCDATA храните HTML в ресурсах exe, по нужде, извлекаете его во временную папку и открываете через Navigate, указав путь к нему.

Comment: если из ресурсов, то лучше из dll. А если из dll, то лучше отдельным файлом, а если отдельным файлом, то лучше html, который писать инсталятором куда надо, лучше в appdata...

Answer (score 2):

И как всегда вечно всё усложняют.

1. Создаешь мемо и браузер.
2. В мемо пишешь исходный код страницы,
3. В браузере при запуске формы пишешь аутбланк и после него присваиваешь браузеру исходный код из мемо
4. И он отобразит твою страницу. Вот и всё!

Ну а дальше дело техники - по своему усмотрению.